# Transform multiple columns of dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a large dataframe with and index and two columns. Each row is a unique aspect about a person. I would like to make a list of dictionaries where the primary key is the name of the person, and then a nested dictionary is built off of that, where each unique instance in the first column is the key and the corresponding cell in the third column is the value.

[image]

The output I am looking for from above dataframe would be:

```
[Bob: {Region: [India], Sector: [Energy, Media and Entertainment]},
 Tom:{Region: [Indonesia], Sector: [Div Financials]}
]
```

I have code to build out the list of unique names, but cannot get the next two layers:

```
individuals_mandate = []
for i in frame.index.unique():
    individuals_mandate.append(i)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big pandas dataframe to dict of some columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291763/big-pandas-dataframe-to-dict-of-some-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.to_dict('index')`. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Should come out exactly how you specified (minus the square brackets)